# Polymer 1.x: Wrapping a jQuery range slider inside a Polymer element

Tags: javascript, jquery, polymer, polymer-1.0, rangeslider

I'm trying to wrap the ion.rangeSlider inside a Polymer element but I'm having trouble [getting it working in a jsBin](http://jsbin.com/dopanumada/1/edit?html,output).

- [Here is the documentation](https://github.com/IonDen/ion.rangeSlider#experiments-playground).
- [Here is a working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/IonDen/qv6yrjrv/).
- [Here is my non-working jsBin](http://jsbin.com/dopanumada/1/edit?html,output).

Please show me how to get this working in a jsBin.

[image]

http://jsbin.com/dopanumada/1/edit?html,output

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">
  <link href="paper-button/paper-button.html" rel="import">

  <script src="http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/static/js/ion-rangeSlider/ion.rangeSlider.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/static/css/ion.rangeSlider.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/static/css/ion.rangeSlider.skinFlat.css">
</head>
<body>

<dom-module id="x-element">

<template>
  <style>
    /** /
    References:
    http://jsfiddle.net/IonDen/qv6yrjrv/
    https://github.com/IonDen/ion.rangeSlider#experiments-playground
    /**/
    body {
        margin: 40px 15px;
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 12px;
    }
    .range-slider {
        position: relative;
        height: 80px;
    }
    .extra-controls {
        position: relative;
        border-top: 3px solid #000;
        padding: 10px 0 0;
    }
  </style>
  <div class="range-slider">
      <input type="text" class="js-range-slider" value="" />
  </div>
  <div class="extra-controls">
      Placeholder for some buttons to change slider behavior
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  (function(){
    Polymer({
      is: "x-element",
      properties: {
      }
    });
  })();
</script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    var $range = $(".js-range-slider");

    $range.ionRangeSlider({
        type: "double",
        min: 100,
        max: 1000,
        from: 300,
        to: 800
    });
  });
</script>

</dom-module>

<x-element></x-element>

</body>
```

Update: [It partially works as shown here](http://jsbin.com/rihirotija/edit?html,output) when I do the following.

1. Move the second `<script>` tag outside the Polymer element template and into the main document body (light DOM).
2. Add the jQuery library resource in the `<head>`.
3. Remove the `$(document).ready(function(){`

But I still need to get it to work with the javascript **inside** the Polymer element template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close with your partially working example, where you called the `ionRangeSlider` function in `ready`. However, you first need to call the jQuery function `$()` with the slider input as an argument.

```
  ready: function(){
    $(this.$.slider).ionRangeSlider({
      type: "double",
      min: 100,
      max: 1000,
      from: 300,
      to: 800
    });
  }
```

[Here's](http://jsbin.com/nibayomuya/edit?html,output) a working jsBin